# How can I get request from .js class which is used for socket io server to laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, axios, socket.io, laravel-8

in Laravel, I am using socket io to detect online and offline users. To do this I use axios to get request to laravel but I got issue like below:  What I am doing wrong?[image][image]

I tried using axios but I got this error. And also Do you have a better advice for getting online and offline users in laravel ?

Comment: Please don't post [images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!